# Detemine whether the interval [4,8] is well-ordered. Explain.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, well-orders

I don't think this interval is well-ordered because the subset (4,8) would not have a smallest value. I'm stuck on how to show (4,8) has no smallest value.

Comment: What's the context of this?  Well-ordered under what ordering structure?  If you mean the standard "$<$" order, then for any $4 < x$ you can always find a $y$ so that $4 < y < x$ so no $x$ can be the smallest  element.  But *are* you asking about the standard "$<$" order?

Answer (score 3):

Assume $(4,8)$ has a smallest value. Name it $x$. Now $4<\frac{4+x}{2}:=y<x$. Therefore $x$ is not the smallest value as $y<x$ and $y\in(4,8)$.